# Migrate Error: Django/Postrgres: DataError Numeric Precision 10000 must be between 1 and 1000

Tags: django, database, postgresql, docker

When trying to migrate changes for the first time into my Postgresql DB, I encounter this error.

I can successfully migrate and start my app when using the standard SQLite db that DJango comes with. However, when trying to connect to my Postgresql I've been having trouble. I have my Postgresql open with pgAdmin and the databases connected with no data in them. I also have deleted all entries in my django app in case an import error was causing the error.

```py
$ docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate
Starting src_db_1 ... done
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, courses, products, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying products.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.DataError: NUMERIC precision 10000 must be between 1 and 1000
LINE 1: ...r(120) NOT NULL, "description" text NULL, "price" numeric(10...
                                                             ^

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  ... 
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.DataError: NUMERIC precision 10000 must be between 1 and 1000
LINE 1: ...r(120) NOT NULL, "description" text NULL, "price" numeric(10...
```

## This is my models.py where I created the price DecimalField.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Product(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120) # max_length = required
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price       = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100,blank=True)
    summary     = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    featured    = models.BooleanField(default=False) # null=True, default=True

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("products:product-detail", kwargs={"id": self.id}) #f"/products/{self.id}/"
```

## This is my manage.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "trydjango.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

```
                                 ^
```

Comment: 1. Try a lower max_digits value. 2. What's the SQL in the migration file that defines the `price` field?

Comment: @EndreBoth ahhhh the Migrations file. You're a god damn genius, thanks mate

Comment: Hi. I have the same error. I try a lower value to max_digits in the shapefile and also in the models.py but none of the attempts worked. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DecimalField.max_digits), `max_digits` is the maximum number of digits allowed meanwhile `decimal_places` is the number of decimal places to store.

For example, if `max_digits = 6` and `decimal_places = 2` means that you will 4 numbers for the digits and 2 for the decimal places (for a total of 6 digits max). Allowing us to store up to 9999,99.

Having said that, I think the error is related to specifying `max_digits = 100`. Try a lower number of digits.